# Want to lock my android app for a given time

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app. I want to lock my app for 10 minutes when enter wrong password 3 times. If i'm using current time stamp for comparing net time then i'm getting my solution but If i'm changing my device time manually from settings then it's not working. Is there any permanent solution for this issue. Thanks to help regarding this.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: Use this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infoweise.applock   and think deeply how they lock apps with time.

Answer (score 0):

For this you cannot use the system time. The best solution is below because it is a local system time.

```
System.nanoTime()
```

According to documetation:

> Returns the current timestamp of the most precise timer available on
>   the local system, in nanoseconds. Equivalent to Linux's
>   CLOCK_MONOTONIC. This timestamp should only be used to measure a
>   duration by comparing it against another timestamp on the same device.
>   Values returned by this method do not have a defined correspondence to
>   wall clock times; the zero value is typically whenever the device last
>   booted. Use currentTimeMillis() if you want to know what time it is.

For reference go through [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could reach out to an internet time service (such as `time.nist.gov` for example).

Someone may have the power to modify their device time but I doubt (blackhats notwithstanding) they'll have the power to reach in and manipulate NIST servers.

But there will be potential problems with any solution, such as no network access, or device owner can intercept DNS lookup for NIST server and so on.

I know at one stage a friend used to roll the time forward by a few hours to get their new allocation of free funds from a slot machine application. But that unfortunately meant the time was always way out from where it should be and rolling back meant even *more* of a delay in future.